# adding html to a laravel blade conditional

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have this to print an address on a report.

```
{{ isset($pref[0]['address']) ? $pref[0]['address'] : '' }}
{{ isset($pref[0]['postcode']) ? $pref[0]['postcode'] : '' }}
{{ isset($pref[0]['phone']) ? $pref[0]['phone'] : '' }}
{{ isset($pref[0]['fax']) ? $pref[0]['fax'] : '' }}
{{ isset($pref[0]['www']) ? $pref[0]['www'] : '' }}
```

but I want to add a `<br>` element to it when the array element has a value.
I tried adding it into the ternary operator, but it prints the `<br>` element as text.

```
`{{ isset($pref[0]['www']) ? $pref[0]['www'].<br> : '' }}`
```

or
    `{{ isset($pref[0]['www']) ? $pref[0]['www'].'<br>' : '' }}`

but it comes through as text and not html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use plain old php

```
<?php ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `{!!  !!}` syntax.

```
{!! isset($pref[0]['address']) ? $pref[0]['address'].'<br>' : '' !!}
{!! isset($pref[0]['postcode']) ? $pref[0]['postcode'].'<br>' : '' !!}
{!! isset($pref[0]['phone']) ? $pref[0]['phone'].'<br>' : '' !!}
{!! isset($pref[0]['fax']) ? $pref[0]['fax'].'<br>' : '' !!}
{!! isset($pref[0]['www']) ? $pref[0]['www'].'<br>' : '' !!}
```

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#displaying-data

Comment: Okay, no what I meant was something like this.
`{{ isset($pref[0]['www']) ? $pref[0]['www'].<br> : '' }}`  so that the <br> does not print id no value was present, but the way it is here it prints the <br> as text. hence the question above.

Comment: Sorry I forget to add `br`s. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In blade you can change the if else short in :

```
@if(isset($pref[0]['address']))
  {{ $pref[0]['address'] }} <br>
@endif


@if(isset($pref[0]['postcode']))
  {{ $pref[0]['postcode'] }} <br>
@endif

...
...
...
...
```